# Problems wire:click on Mobile-Tablet Views

Tags: php, events, dom-events, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I want to tell you that I have problems with my laravel livewire application I have several **wire:click** events but when rendering the components (views) on tablet or mobile none of the events work, the ajax request is not made **(on laptop it works perfectly),**

```
<button wire:click="$emitTo('persona.modal','abrirModal',{{ $persona->id }})"class="w-4 mx-2 transform hover:text-blue-800 hover:scale-125"></button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OhkE.png)

in laptop: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OhkE.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO0Ht.png
in mobile: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OhkE.png)

my code:
view.blade.php(tabla.blade.php)

```
<div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-2 xl:mt-2 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-1">
        <table class="cell-border compact stripe compact tablas">
            <thead class="">
                <tr
                    class="">
                    <th class="p-2">Tipo documento</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Documento</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Nombre</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Teléfono</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Correo electrónico</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Dirección</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Estado</th>
                    <th class="p-2">Fecha registro</th>
                    <th class="p-3 text-center" width="110px">Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="flex-1 sm:flex-none">
                @if ($personas)
                    @foreach ($personas as $persona)
                        <tr class="flex flex-col flex-no wrap sm:table-row mb-2 sm:mb-0 hover:bg-gray-100">
                            <td class="border-grey-light border  p-3">
                                {{ $persona->tipo_doc }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                {{ $persona->documento }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                {{ $persona->nombres . ' ' . $persona->apellidos }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                {{ $persona->telefono }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                {{ $persona->correo }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                {{ $persona->direccion }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                <span class="px-2 py-1 font-semibold  @if ($persona->users->estado == 1) {{ 'bg-green-100' }}@else {{ 'bg-red-100' }}@endif rounded-sm">
                                    {{ $persona->users->estado == 1 ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo' }}
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                {{ $persona->created_at }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="border-grey-light border p-3">
                                <div class="flex item-center justify-center">
                                    <a href="{{ route('persona.detalle',$persona) }}"
                                        class="w-4 mx-2 transform hover:text-blue-800 hover:scale-125">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                            stroke="currentColor">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                                d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z" />
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                                d="M2.458 12C3.732 7.943 7.523 5 12 5c4.478 0 8.268 2.943 9.542 7-1.274 4.057-5.064 7-9.542 7-4.477 0-8.268-2.943-9.542-7z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                    <button wire:click="$emitTo('persona.modal','abrirModal',{{ $persona->id }})"
                                        class="w-4 mx-2 transform hover:text-blue-800 hover:scale-125">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                            stroke="currentColor">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                                d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    <button wire:click="$emit('eliminarJs',{{ $persona->id }})"
                                        class="w-4 mx-2 transform hover:text-blue-800 hover:scale-125">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                            stroke="currentColor">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                                d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    @push('js')
        <script>
            Livewire.on('eliminarJs', ($persona) => {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Esta seguro de eliminar este registro?',
                    text: "Si la persona no tiene planes asignados se borrarán los datos tano del usuario como del cliente",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Si, confirmar!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        Livewire.emitTo('persona.modal', 'eliminar', $persona);
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Registro eliminado!',
                            'Registro eliminado correctamente.',
                            'success',
                        )
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

myclass.php(tabla.php)

```
protected $listeners = [
        'render',
        'limpiarFiltros'    
    ];
   
  public function abrirModal(Sede $sedes)
    {
        $this->emitTo('sede.modal','abrirModal', $sedes);
    }
```

my-class-listener(Modal.php)

```
public $mostrarModal = 'hidden';
    public $titulo = 'Nuevo registro';

    public $nombre_sede = '';
    public $direccion = '';
    public $telefono = '';
    public $persona_cargo = '';

    public Sede $sede;

    protected $listeners = [
        'abrirModal',
        'eliminar'
    ];
 public function abrirModal(Sede $sedes)
    {
        if ($sedes->exists) {
            $this->sede = $sedes;
            //actualizar registro
            $this->nombre_sede = $sedes->nombre_sede;
            $this->direccion = $sedes->direccion;
            $this->telefono = $sedes->telefono;
            $this->persona_cargo = $sedes->persona_cargo;
            $this->titulo = "Actualizar registro";
            $this->mostrarModal = '';
        } else {
            //nuevo registro
            $this->sede = new Sede;
            $this->titulo = "Nuevo registro";
            $this->mostrarModal = '';
        }
        
    }
```

my view-parent(sede.blade.php)

```
<div class="py-10">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
            <section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
                <div class="container px-6 py-7 mx-auto">
                    <div class="bg-slate-100/50 py-1 px-3 border-solid border-b rounded-lg">
                        <x-titulo titulo="Listar Sedes"></x-titulo>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-4 xl:mt-4 md:grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-1 justify-items-end">
                        <x-jet-secondary-button wire:click="abrirModal"
                            class="bg-black hover:bg-gray-700 text-white hover:text-white">
                            Nueva Sede
                        </x-jet-secondary-button>
                    </div>
                    @livewire('sede.tabla')
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@livewire('sede.modal')
```

Comment: Ok, not much to go on here. What does the rest of your view look like, how have you tested and verified this?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it, I'm using Datatables Jquery with its responsive library, this blocked my livewire $emit in mobile or tablet size, greetings friends

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).